# Como actualizar un dataset para añadir una tabla que recién cree en mi BD?

Tags: c#, dataset

Tengo un dataset con tableadapters que necesito, por alguna modificacion tuve que crear una nueva tabla en la BD, quiero crear el tableadapter para esa tabla sin embargo me dice que el objeto no existe, ya intente reiniciando el servicio de SQLServer para forzar a actualizar la informacion pero sigue sin aparecerme en VisualStudio, incluso cuando desde la BD yo ya realice consultas a esa misma tabla. Saben de que podria tratarse? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]